# Is it possible to set conditional validation in cerberus, Python?

Tags: python-3.x, validation, conditional-statements, cerberus

I use Python package [cerberus](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/index.html) to validate my payload
Here's my issue:

I need to set a field to be required only if some field from another schema has exact value. Something like:

```
    "key2": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": \\\ true if dict1.key1 == 'valueX' else false \\\
    }
```

So My schema should look like:

```
"dict1": {
  "type": "dict",
  "schema": {
    "key1": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  }
},
"dict2": {
  "type": "dict",
  "schema": {
    "key2": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": \\\ true if dict1.key1 == 'valueX' else false \\\
    }
  }
}
```

Does somebody know the way, how to achieve it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm too is struggling with this, here is a shorter example one what I hoped would work using dependencies. I'm posting this as an answer (but community wiki) since the code block tends to not look good in comments. Hope that's okay, rather than creating a separate question.

**Shorter reproducable example**

```
schema = {
    'field1': {
        'required': True
    }, 
    'field2': {
        'required': True,      
         'dependencies': {
             'field1': 'one'
         }
    }
}

>>> document = {'field1': 'two'}
>>> v.validate(document, schema)
False
>>> print(v.errors)

{'field2': ['required field']}
```

Doing the above would from my understand make field2 be required if field 1 equals "one".

My second try was to not make it required:

```
schema = {
    'field1': {
        'required': True
    }, 
    'field2': {
        'required': False,      
         'dependencies': {
             'field1': 'one'
         }
    }
}
```

That however passes the tests:

```
>>> document = {'field1': 'one'}
>>> v.validate(document, schema)
True
>>> print(v.errors)

{}
```

And only fails them if I try to supply a value in "field2" when "field1" don't have an approved value:

```
>>> document = {'field1': 'two', 'field2': 'test'}
>>> v.validate(document, schema)
False
>>> print(v.errors)

{'field2': ["depends on these values: {'field1': 'one'}"]}
```

So I don't think this use case is supported by Cerberus, or if it is, I haven't found the right combination yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the documentation but havent't fount the answer.
In your example, I'm not sure it really works. Moreover, I think dependencies works differently to my example. But maybe I'm wrong.

It looks like dependecies in sub-schemas does not work.
Your example returns error message:

```
from cerberus import Validator
schema = {"dict1": {
        "type": "dict",
        "schema": {
            "key1": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": True,
                "allowed": ["valueX"]
            }
        }
    },
    "dict2": {
        "type": "dict",
        "schema": {
            "key2": {  # required if dependency matches
                "type": "string",
                "dependencies": {
                    "dict1.key1": ["valueX"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
payload = {
    "dict1": {
                "key1": 'valueX'
            },
     "dict2": {
                "key2": 'some_value'
            }       
    }

validator = Validator(schema)
if validator(payload):
    print('Super!')
else:
    print(str(validator.errors))
```

with error:

```
{'dict2': [{'key2': ["depends on these values: {'dict1.key1': ['valueX']}"]}]}
```

But it worked when I tried to set dependency for "dict2"

```
schema = {"dict1": {
        "type": "dict",
        "schema": {
            "key1": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": True#,
                #"allowed": ["valueX"]
            }
        }
    },
    "dict2": {
        "type": "dict",
        "dependencies": {
                    "dict1.key1": "sms"
                },
        "schema": {
            "key2": {  # required if dependency matches
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case I'm wrong please, let me know. The solution would really help me.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

most of the time you'll find solutions in a library's documentation.
What you are looking for is under "**dependencies**"
A Link to the Cerberus documentation and the corresponding section can be found here:
https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#dependencies

In the Documentation it says:

---

> When a mapping is provided, not only all dependencies must be present, but also any of their allowed values must be matched.
>
> ---
>
> Declaring dependencies on subdocument fields with dot-notation is also supported:

---

For your example it simply means, that if your requirement is bound to a value, the value must match to any value specified with the "allowed" rule.
If your requirement is bound to a schema, you can specify that schema and its subschemas by the dot notation.

A solution that should work for you would look like this:

```
"dict1": {
    "type": "dict",
    "schema": {
        "key1": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": True,
            "allowed": ["valueX"]
        }
    }
},
"dict2": {
    "type": "dict",
    "schema": {
        "key2": {  # required if dependency matches
            "type": "string",
            "dependencies": {
                "dict1.key1": ["valueX"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if that also works when you don't specify any 'allowed' rule at all, but I'd pretty much guess that it should.

Comment: thank you for the comment, but it does not work (check my answer from tMay 26. If I'm doing something wrong, please, let me know. Thanks

Comment: you're on the right track here with the dependencies rule, but you're mixing up the relations as if it was the required rule. also look closely how to address lop-level fields w/ dot-notation. and reading the docs is surely the best advice. :-) btw, your markup is messy.